# ASP.NET SQL Membership Provider in Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight-4.0, asp.net-membership

I want to use ASP.NET SQL Membership Provider in a Silverlight 4 application.

I was able to get to the point (using the AuthenticationService) where I can log in an user. But I don't know how to create one and I really need a push in the right direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it the first time is to use the web administrator.

This article though it may be dated should give you some direction:

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202857/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx

Comment: My issue is Silverlight specific. I wanted to create a user from code-behind

Comment: I have been able to create users and manage them using Javascript. So for it to be Silverlight or Flex. I don't really think it matters.